# file permission and ownership Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Environments aws

Tags: php, docker

Is there any way to set file permission and ownership on files deployed on Docker container on Elastic Beanstalk Multicontainer Docker Environment.
There are two custom containers nginx and php-fpm. Php-fpm process runs as www-data (user and group) and currently all the files deployed under /var/www/html are owned by root:root. I was looking to use .ebextensions however this probably can only solve file permission but not sure what to do with ownership, change from root to www-data?

Comment: Change the ownership in your Dockerfile ;) The inside of the container is outside the scope of EBT.

Comment: Sure but "/var/www/html" is a mount point and after deployment ( Dockerrun.aws.json) all files inside are root:root...